# Existe alguma maneira de rodar um seed somente uma vez?

Tags: php, cakephp-3, migrations

Eu utilizo o framework CakePhp 3, estava pesquisando sobre migrations e seeds e fiz alguns teste, os migrations eles rodam apenas uma vez por conta da tabela de sphinx log, porém se eu fizer um seed e chamar ele de xSeed, e rodar esse seed na linha de comando, depois criar um ySeed e rodar ele, ele vai rodar tanto o ySeed quanto o xSeed, tem alguma forma de eu controlar isso?